# Identity ASP.NET Core register modifying

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I'm trying to modify ASP.NET Core Identity's register. I've added in database two properties (FirstName and LastName) then I've modified `OnPostAsync` func for adding them into db in `Register.cshtml.cs` but it's throwing exception:

> SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be
> called on Null values, so what i need to to for exception evaporate

Register.cshtml.cs

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<AuthSysUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<AuthSysUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IUserStore<AuthSysUser> _userStore;
    private readonly IUserEmailStore<AuthSysUser> _emailStore;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<AuthSysUser> userManager,
        IUserStore<AuthSysUser> userStore,
        SignInManager<AuthSysUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _userStore = userStore;
        _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    public class InputModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }


    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = CreateUser();
            user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
            user.LastName = Input.LastName;
            await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
            await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }

    private AuthSysUser CreateUser()
    {
        try
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance<AuthSysUser>();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(AuthSysUser)}'. " +
                $"Ensure that '{nameof(AuthSysUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
        }
    }

    private IUserEmailStore<AuthSysUser> GetEmailStore()
    {
        if (!_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
        }
        return (IUserEmailStore<AuthSysUser>)_userStore;
    }
}
```

Modified function:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = CreateUser();
        /*added code*/user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
        /*added code*/user.LastName = Input.LastName;
        await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
            var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                pageHandler: null,
                values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                protocol: Request.Scheme);

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

            if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            else
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your database if the newly added properties to the user exists within the user table. If not, create a migration and update the database.